# c# Sign a SOAP envelope webrequest with a 509 cert

Tags: c#, soap, x509certificate, signature

I'm working with a third party that refuses to fix their scheme for a published WSDL. The issue is the SOAP service is expecting different name spaces than the WSDL is providing. So in my C# app I'm having a lot of trouble using the Proxy by .Net. In an attempt to work around this I want to just send a web-request and package up my data

I just can't figure out how to add my signature to the header of my request.

```
 Microsoft.Web.Services3.SoapEnvelope soapEnvelopeXml = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.SoapEnvelope();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://Illinois-stage.tylerhost.net/efm/FilingReviewMDEPort.svc");
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction:\"urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServicesProfile-Definitions-4.0/FilingReviewMDEPort/ReviewFilingRequest\"");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("MIME-Version: 1.0");
            request.ContentType = "multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\";start=\"<http://tempuri.org/0>\";boundary=\"uuid:936f2c7e-590a-4f19-b154-ce8285adf18a+id=2\";start-info=\"text/xml\"";
            request.Method = "POST";

            soapEnvelopeXml.Load(@"c:\temp\ReviewFilingRequest.xml");

            System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken securityToken = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken(X509);
            Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityToken signatureToken   = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityToken(X509);

            MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);

            ////////// XmlDocumentFragment xfrag = soapEnvelopeXml.CreateDocumentFragment();
            //////////xfrag.InnerXml = messageHeader;
            //////////soapEnvelopeXml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(xfrag);

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
            xmlDoc.Save(xmlStream);

            using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateMtomWriter(xmlStream, Encoding.UTF8, int.MaxValue, "text/xml", "uuid:936f2c7e-590a-4f19-b154-ce8285adf18a+id=2", "http://tempuri.org/0",false,false))
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.WriteTo(writer);
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(xmlStream.ToArray(),0, xmlStream.ToArray().Length );
                }
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                      string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                      Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up signing it in Node.js Making the switch to node gave me a lot more control over the message. As an added bonus I didn't have to pay the Microsoft Tax.

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=soap&page=1&ranking=optimal

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that might be able to help.

1. What error message are you getting back? Access Denied (or something along those lines)?
2. Have you tried looking at which headers you are missing? The best way to do this is to download WireShark or Telerik's Fiddler which allows HTTPS decryption. Using one of these, you can access the website in an internet browser and view the headers that are being sent through a normal browser.